# Calculating datetime difference from separate rows and add them to get total

Tags: mysql

Click link below to see image. 
I need to get the time diff highlighted in red and the time diff in blue. Then add the time together to get the total.

Below is the query that will show all the records. 
The first 2 records i will need to get the time difference, which will be around 3 days 4 hours and the last 2 records should only be 2 mins. So in total it should be AROUND 3 days 4 hours and 2 mins.
[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Wbt.png)

```
select so
    , createDate
    , o
    , n 
from userTrans 
where ( n = 10 OR  o = 10 ) and so = 'g220'
```

Below will show that i grouped the records to get the total time. This is not what i want because it is getting the min and max time diff. The result turns out to be 32 hours.

```
select so
                , min(createDate) minDate
                , max(createDate) maxDate
                , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, min(createDate), max(createDate)) diff
                , CONCAT(
            FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(min(createDate), max(createDate))) / 24), ' days ',
            MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(min(createDate), max(createDate))), 24), ' hours ',
            MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(min(createDate), max(createDate))), ' minutes') diff1 
                , count(*) hits
            from userTrans 
            where ( n = 10 OR  o = 10 ) and so = 'g220'

            group by so
            order by TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, min(createDate), max(createDate)) DESC
```

Will this be possible to achieve? I hope I was clear.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use a MySQL version 8.0 or MariaDB-10.2+ that have recursive CTE's enabled? So the interval(s) are from `o=0` to the next row in with the same `so`?

Comment: Can you copy/paste that data into the question please? (Don't use images of data and we won't use images of answers.)

Comment: @ danblack - thank you for your response. The below answer is what I was looking for but to answer your question, it is MariaDB

Comment: @ User_By_Already - Thanks for the tip. Will keep that in mind, when posting again in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to align the 2 date/time references for a calculation.

```
SELECT
    *
   , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(createDate,nextcreatedate))
FROM (
    SELECT
        so
      , createDate
      , (
            SELECT
                createDate
            FROM table1 AS t2
            WHERE t2.so = t1.so
            AND t2.createDate > t1.createDate
            ORDER BY
                CreaDate
            LIMIT 1
        )
        AS nextcreatedate
      , n
      , test
    FROM table1 AS t1
    WHERE o = 0
) d
```

In other dbms systems using `lead()` might provide a more convenient of getting the next needed createdate value.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the answer. I had to make a slight modification to fit my situation but it gave me results I am looking for. Thanks again!!